# rendering data in jsp using spring controllers and different classes

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc

i want to render data

this is how my jsp page table look like
[image: this is what a table look like]

how i achieve this,

please help me,

it creates a lot of confusion for me, that how many classes are to be define and what are the fields.

thanks

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Most likely your data is coming from database and this is kind of `List` of javabeans returned.

Let's say this is:

```
List<MyObjects> objects
```

You need to set it in controller level:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/table")
public ModelAndView renderTable() {
    ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("/table"); 
    mv.add("objects",objects);
    return mv;
}
```

Now this is the way you render it on the JSP:

```
<c:if test="${not empty objects}">
    <table>
        <c:forEach var="o" items="${objects}">
            <tr>
                <td>${o.id}</td>
                <td>${o.name}</td>
                <td>${o.descriptio}</td>   
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
    </table>
</c:if>
```

You can read about it more here:
http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.1.RELEASE/reference/html/view.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer.But,It will not work unless you add a dollar symbol before all the jstl statements.