# How To Display Data in Columns Using Spring MVC and JSP?

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc, jstl

I want to take some data from the database and arrange it into rows with each row having 4 columns. Tables or css come to mind. By the way, I do not need borders.

What's a clean way to do this? If I use tables, I would have to count how many cells have been done in a row and in the last row add some empty cells to that row. Right? What is a better way?

I am using Spring MVC JSPs and looked at the associated docs. http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/view.html

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[rendering data in jsp using spring controllers and different classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4930581/rendering-data-in-jsp-using-spring-controllers-and-different-classes/4930905#4930905)

I think it answer your question completely.

Comment: Thank you for your response. The link you shared shows how to loop over objects and how to display properties of that object in a table row. I was looking for how to loop over strings and have 4 of those strings in the same row. Also it would have to handle the case where the number of strings is not a multiple of 4. Thanks!

Comment: This is closest. Have a great day!

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest something like this:

```
<table id="list">
<thead class="dataTableHeader">
    <tr>
        <td><fmt:message key="items.header"/></td>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <c:if test="${fn:length(yourForm.items.count) < 4}">
        <tr>
            //add some empty rows
        </tr>
    </c:if>
        <c:forEach var="item" items="${yourForm.items}">
            <tr>
                <td>${item.id}</td>
                                    // and other colums
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
</tbody>
```

Comment: something like that, true.  I think a counter would be used and once the 4th cell in a row is done it can complete the row and start another. A check would have to be done to handle the case of empty cells. Example: outputting 10 items results in 3 rows with the 3rd row containing 2 empty cells.