# Spring Mvc display data from multiple Lists in Jsp

Tags: java, spring-mvc, arraylist, foreach, model

Hi there I am using Spring MVC and I am trying to display some data **from multiple Lists** in a jsp page. I've searched and found some similar topics but I wasn't able to achieve what I am trying to do plus got more confused.
My **model class** contains something like this:

```
private String BlaBla1;

private String BlaBla2;

private List<String> Alpha;

private List<String> Beta; 
.....
//getters setters
```

What I want is to display a **table** in a jsp with the values from these two **Lists** (*Alpha* and *Beta* ..) **one value at a column**.They both have the **same number** of values.
For Example

```
<tr><td>Alpha.value1</td><td>Beta.value1</td></tr>
<tr><td>Alpha.value2</td><td>Beta.value2</td></tr>
......................................
<tr><td>Alpha.valueN</td><td>Beta.valueN</td></tr>
```

As I've seen here [rendering data in jsp using spring controllers and different classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4930581/rendering-data-in-jsp-using-spring-controllers-and-different-classes/4930905#4930905)

and some other examples, they create something like that: `List<MyObjects> objects` but MyObjects model always has private String ... and **NOT** any `List<String>..`

I tried to construct something like that

```
Map<String,List<String>> test = new HashMap<String,List<String>>();
```

then

```
test.put("alfa", Alpha);
test.put("beta", Beta);
```

but all I got was just display them in **2** rows and a single column using

```
<c:forEach var="testValue" items="${test}">
    <tr><td>${testValue.value}</td></tr>
</c:forEach>
```

Please don't aske me to change my Model class, it is 'impossible'.
I've seen somewhere saying to use Collection but I'm not sure how to do that.

Any suggestion would be useful,
happy coding!

Comment: "but all I got was just display them in N rows and a single column using." Does this mean you are now getting all the correct list data displayed but it's just all displayed incorrectly i.e in a single column? Is that what's wrong?

Comment: Well to be honest not exactly..you are right!All I get is all the values from each List in a row..so all values from Alpha List in row 1 and all values from Beta List in row 2..So no, they are not displayed correctly!I just can't use ${testValue.Alpha}</td><td>${testValue.Beta}</td></tr> as in other examples as above with the List<MyObjects>
I am editing my original post (Sorry)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
model.addObject("alphaList", alpha);
model.addObject("betaList", beta);
```

In the jsp :

```
<c:forEach var="listItem" items="${alphaList}" varStatus="theCount" >
    <tr><td>${listItem}</td><td>${betaList[theCount.index]}</td></tr>
</c:forEach>
```

> Note : `${theCount.index}` starts with 0 
>          `${theCount.count}` starts with 1.

So basically you can use the count to iterate over the second list.

Comment: Thank you @Nikhil and credits to Serge Ballesta for his answer too!

Answer (score 1):

You just have to iterate the `Alpha` list normally ... but with use of the `varStatus` attribute of `<c:foreach >` tag. This `varStatus` has (among others) an attribute `index` which is the index of the iteration and all what you need to display corresponding element from `Beta` list. Code example :

```
<c:forEach var="alphaVal" items="${Alpha}" varStatus="status">
    <tr><td>${alphaVal}</td><td>${Beta[status.index]}</td></tr>
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: Oh hi thanks for posting. I'll try that also but I have one small question..where do I put Beta in the controller? I mean should I use model.addAttribute("..", Alpha); and 
model.addAttribute("..", Beta); or Should I put them inside another List or Map-HashMap? I've tried many things and I am lost..